# Как передвинуть объект на одну координату?

Tags: c++

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
bool gameOver;
int x = 10;
int y = 10;
enum eDirection {STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN};
eDirection dir;
void Setup() {
    gameOver = false;
}

void Draw() {
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) 
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            if (j == 0 || j == 19)
                cout << "#";
            if (i == y && j == x)
                cout << "0";
            else cout << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        cout << "#";


}

void inPut() {
    if (_kbhit()) {
        switch (_getch()) {
        case 'a':
            dir = LEFT;
            break;
        case 'd':
            dir = RIGHT;
            break;
        case 'w':
            dir = UP;
            break;
        case 's':
            dir = DOWN;
            break;
        case 'x':
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }
}

void Logic() {
    switch(dir) {
    case LEFT:
        x--;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        x++;
        break;
    case UP:
        y--;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        y++;
        break;
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Setup();
    while (!gameOver) {
        Draw();
        inPut();
        Logic();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Это - часть кода от игры в "змейку". При нажатии клавиш awsd кружок начинает двигаться постоянно в одном и том же направлении (вечно). Как сделать так, что бы при нажатии, кружочек передвигался только на одну клеточку (координату). Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Вероятно, вы не очищаете поток ввода. Может, это исправит вашу проблему

Comment: Странно, у меня работает (компилятор mingw, запускал через wine)

Comment: Сама программа работает, но кружок начинает двигаться бесконечно, а мне нужно чтобы при нажатии, он сдвигался только на один символ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
bool gameOver;
int x = 10;
int y = 10;
enum eDirection { STOP = 0, LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN };
eDirection dir;
void Setup() {
    gameOver = false;
}

void Draw() {
    system("cls");
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        cout << "#";
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
            if (j == 0 || j == 19)
                cout << "#";
            if (i == y && j == x)
                cout << "0";
            else cout << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
        cout << "#";


}

void inPut() {
    if (_kbhit()) {
        switch (_getch()) {
        case 'a':
            x--;
            break;
        case 'd':
            x++;
            break;
        case 'w':
            y--;
            break;
        case 's':
            y++;
            break;
        case 'x':
            gameOver = true;
        }
    }
}

void Logic() {
    switch (dir) {
    case LEFT:
        x--;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        x++;
        break;
    case UP:
        y--;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        y++;
        break;
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    Setup();
    while (!gameOver) {
        Draw();
        inPut();
        Logic();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Вот, как то так. Просто вместо dir сразу прописуем изменения координат)

Comment: Спасибо, вот это реально работает!

Comment: Норм) Отметь, что ответ правильный, что бы вопрос больше не висел)

Comment: Просто и сам змейку по видео писал)

Answer (score 0):

вы не сбрасываете переменную dir, один раз нажали клавишу ибудет ехать до переполнения координат.

Попробуйте так:

```
void Logic() {
    switch (dir) {
    case LEFT:
        x--;
        break;
    case RIGHT:
        x++;
        break;
    case UP:
        y--;
        break;
    case DOWN:
        y++;
        break;
    }

    dir = STOP; // Добавляем
}
```

Тогда на каждом такте в зависимости от ввода будет совершаться строго одно действие.

Дополнительно:
Чтобы уменьшить мерцание консоли вместо `system("cls");`
используйте

```
#include <Windows.h> // надо для работы
...

SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), COORD{0, 0});
```